# call asp.net method from jquery dialog button

Tags: jquery

I am tying to create delete confirmation dialog.
Here's my jquery dialog

```
$(function () {
    $("#del-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        modal: true,
        close: function (event, ui) {
            location.reload(false);
        },
        buttons: {
            'Delete': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                // delete function goes here

             },
             'Cancel': function () {
                  $(this).dialog('close');
              }
        },
   });

   $(".icon-del").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#del-dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

And my asp code:

```
    l += "<a onclick='hello(";
                l += dr["cID"].ToString();
                l += ");'>";
                l += "</a>";
```

How do I handle delete function from dialog button?

Comment: More detail needed are you referring to getting access to your code behind? if so i would suggest an ajax call see here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $("#del-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        modal: true,
        close: function (event, ui) {
            location.reload(false);
        },
        buttons: {
            'Delete': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                var target=$("#del-dialog").data("event").currentTarget
                $(target).data('isConfirming', true); 
                target.click();
                $(target).data('isConfirming', null);

             },
             'Cancel': function () {
                  $(this).dialog('close');
              }
        },
   });

   $(".icon-del").click(function (event) {
       if($(event.currentTarget).data('isConfirming')) return;
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#del-dialog").data("event",event);
        $("#del-dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```